# How to say "I got disconnected" and "I'm lagging"?

Tags: word-choice, slang

I'm playing an online game on a Chinese server, and I sometimes get disconnected when the VPN gets congested. When this happens, I have to restart the game and re-enter the map, while the rest of my group is probably wondering what I'm doing.

How do I explain to my group that I got disconnected from the server?

I've also seen people complain use 卡 to complain that they're lagging, but I guess it could just as well refer to being stuck. Is there a less ambiguous way to refer to network lag?

Comment: 卡 isn't ambiguous at all.

Comment: Btw, most gamers would understand what **LAG** means.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"掉线了“ means "I got disconnected" in Chinese,the pronunciation is "diao xian le", and "掉了” in short.
As for "I'm lagging", you can say "网络很卡“，the pronunciation is "wang luo hen ka". Usually a Chinese guy can also easily get your meaning if you express it in "卡”.